# How do I show that any cycle of length $n$ can be rewritten as a product of $n-1$ transpositions $(1 \; \; 2),(2 \; \; 3),...,(n-1 \; \; n)$?

Tags: euclidean-geometry, symmetric-groups, permutation-cycles

The problem is from "Notes on Geometry" by Rees.

> Show that any $\sigma \in S_n$ can be writen as a product involving only the $(n-1)$ transpositions $(1,2),(2,3),...,((n-1),n)$.

- Note: In the book, $S_n$ denotes the symmetric group on $n$ letters. But, in this problem, I think it specifically means natural numbers $1,...,n$ because it doesn't make any sense if it is not (as ndhanson3 said in the comment.)

To prove the statement, first, I showed that any $\sigma \in S_n$ can be rewritten as a product of transpositions.

And then, I showed that $\sigma$ is also a product of transpositions $(1 \; \; 2),(2 \; \; 3),...,(n-1 \; \; n)$.

Now, I'm left with the last step, which is to show that any $\sigma$ is a product of exactly $n-1$ transpositions $(1 \; \; 2),(2 \; \; 3),...,(n-1 \; \; n)$.

I thought I could show it with the inductive method as other answers suggested, but all the answers I could find only showed that $\sigma$ is a product of $n-1$ transpositions (but these transpositions might not be $(1 \; \; 2),(2 \; \; 3),...,(n-1 \; \; n)$.)

Anyways, for the inductive method, I showed that it satisfies for $n=2$ case, then I assumed that it also satisfies for $n=k-1$ case. And here's my work for the $n=k$ case.

Let $\sigma = (a_1 \; \; a_2 \;\; ... a_{k-1} \;\;a_k)$ for arbitrary $a_1,...,a_k \in \{1,...,k\}$, but each $a$'s are distinct.

Then, $\exists a_i \in \{a_1,...,a_k\}$ s.t $ a_i =k$.

But, note that we can always place $k$ in the last place of the cycle. Then, we can decompose the $\sigma$ as $k-2$ many of $(1 \; \; 2),(2 \; \; 3),...,(k-2 \; \; k-1)$ and the other transposition $(a_j \;\;a_i)$ where $a_j \neq a_i$.

We can observe that if $|a_j -a_i|=1$, then there are $k-1$ many transpositions as we desired. However, it is not really clear when $|a_j-a_i|\neq 1$.

I know that we can rewrite such $(a_j \;\; a_i)$ as a product of transpositions like $(a_j \;\; a_{j+1})...(a_{i-1} \;\; a_i)...(a_j \;\; a_{j+1})$. For example, $(1 \; \; 3) = (1 \;\; 2)(2 \;\;3)(1 \; \;2)$, but then I think there must be more than $k-1$ transpositions.

Is there anything I'm missing here? What are the alternative ways to prove the statement?

Comment: I think the question specifically requires $n$, the length of the cycle to equal the $n$ of $S_n$. The transposition $(1\, 3)$ in $S_3$ certainly can't be written as a product of $2-1=1$ transposition $(1\, 2)$ or $(2\, 3)$. Therefore the arbitrary $\sigma$ that you have for the proof isn't of arbitrary length $k$. Where did this question come from? Provide the exact wording if you want confirmation that this is the intent.

Comment: @ndhanson3 Thanks for letting me know! I added the exact wording of the problem.

Comment: I think the $n-1$ in the problem statement refers to the number of distinct available transpositions, not how "long" the final product turns out to be.

Comment: @Arthur Then, this just means that we can rewrite it as a product of such transpositions! Not restricted to the number of transpositions. I spent so much time on this because of my misinterpretation. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Yes! Unfortunately, it is the word "the" in the problem statement that you left out in your title that really makes the question read the way it is. The difference between "I have five apples" and "I have the five apples" is, in the latter, there is an understanding of five specific apples that I am referring to, while the former seems to stress the idea that I have five of them, not more or less.